# Is it ok leaving a CoreBluetooth scan running forever?

Tags: ios, core-bluetooth

Is it ok to start a Core Bluetooth scan using `scanForPeripheralsWithServices:options:` and leave it running for the entire time my app is active? I'm trying to figure out if its:

A. Frowned upon.

B. Bad for battery life.

C. Creates heat.

D. Has any negative effects whatsoever that I might not know about.

Comment: I'd say B. But it depends on your app. Is it like LightBlue (which seems to be ok for me in that case), or is it done to connect to an amount of devices limited each time (just communicate with one for example), then you don't need to scan once you've done the connection.

Comment: In my case, the user will probably be disconnected from the device most of the time. I just need it to silently/automatically reconnect when they get close. It's just one device so I could stop the scan once it's connected.

Comment: If you have identified a target device then you can issue a connect and the connect will complete automatically when the device is in range. You don't need to keep the periperal scan running. See the lock example in the core Bluetooth programming guide for more information

Comment: That's awesome, thanks Paul. Definitely looks like the correct way to solve this problem. Here's the relevant info from the apple docs: "At this point, the app can simply call the connectPeripheral:options: method of the CBCentralManager class, and because connection requests do not time out, the iOS device will reconnect when the user returns home."

Answer (score 0):

CoreBluetooth actually has features that support this type of behavior. CB has been designed with all of these things that you list in mind, and Apple has brilliantly integrated CoreBluetooth with State Preservation and Restoration (https://developer.apple.com/library/archive/documentation/NetworkingInternetWeb/Conceptual/CoreBluetooth_concepts/CoreBluetoothBackgroundProcessingForIOSApps/PerformingTasksWhileYourAppIsInTheBackground.html) to allow you to write apps that run for days and even weeks.

Essentially, even if the operating system decides to close your application to free up memory or your device run out of power and dies (after restarting the device), you will still be able to perform a set of BLE-related activities, including scanning and connecting to BLE peripherals.

I have implemented this myself and am still amazed at how well it works. Replicating the same performance on Android is possible but has been a nightmare; on iOS "it just works".